# Syntax error with if statement in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble with a "Syntax Error: invalid syntax" message in python code that keeps moving the goals posts on me.

Here's the sample code:

```
another_answer = int(raw_input("> ")

if another_answer == 1:
    print "The pirate's body slowly goes limp and he whispers to you......."
    print "Good luck my son.  You might need this."
    get_gold()

    print: "Do you want to continue to the next room?"
```

When I run this in the shell I get the following:

```
File "ex36.py", line 179
  if another_answer == 1:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found this bizarre, and after removing the colon I got an error message on the next line:

```
File "ex36.py", line 180
print "The pirate's body slowly goes limp and he slowly whispers to you......."
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Similar questions I've found on stackoverflow center around improper spacing and indentation, but I've looked that over and everything seems to be well.

Comment: Well, there _is_ an indentation error here; the `if` statement has to be at the same indentation level as the `another_answer =` statement. But there's _another_ syntax error that prevents you from seeing that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preceding line is missing a closing parenthesis:

```
another_answer = int(raw_input("> ")
#                   ^         ^    ^^
#                    \         \--//
#                     \-----------?
```

Python allows expressions to cross physical lines when enclosed in parentheses, so when you *don't* close parentheses Python continues to look for the rest of the expression. By the time it reaches the `:` the expression makes no sense anymore and a `SyntaxError` exception is raised.

Comment: This is abit chatty but, when ever I open question for Python I find Martijn Pieters. Is there anything you don't know about Python. Hands off!

Comment: Have commented similar comment before, because been a fan from day 1. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on the first line. The colon is simply the first character which couldn't possibly be part of an actual function argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems, and you have to fix both.

The first is that you're missing a closing parenthesis:

```
another_answer = int(raw_input("> ")
```

This means that Python is still trying to compile the arguments to the call to `int` when it gets to the next line. Until the colon, everything is still legal, because you could have been writing this:

```
another_answer = int(raw_input("> ")
                     if another_answer == 1
                     else '42')
```

But once you get to the colon, there is no valid expression that could appear in, so that's where you get the `SyntaxError`.

In general, when you get a `SyntaxError` on a line where absolutely nothing looks wrong, look to the previous line—usually it's a missing `)` (or `]` or `}`).

---

However, if you fix that, you're going to have another problem. Although you claim this:

> Similar questions I've found on stackoverflow center around improper spacing and indentation, but I've looked that over and everything seems to be well.

… everything is definitely *not* well:

```
another_answer = int(raw_input("> ")

    if another_answer == 1:
```

That `if` statement is indented to the right of that `another_answer` statement. That's illegal, and will raise an `IndentationError`. You can only change indentation levels in Python to enter or exit a block controlled by a compound statement.

---

You've also got at least one more error in your code:

```
print: "Do you want to continue to the next room?"
```

This will raise a `SyntaxError`. `print` isn't a compound statement like `if` or `def`, so it doesn't take a colon.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find you missed a closing parenthesis at the first line.